# WebDAV# SqlExample missing assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, webdav

I just cloned the [WebDAVSharp.SQLExample](https://github.com/Winterleaf/Winterleaf-WebDavSharp.SQLExample) repo from winterleaf. It uses the [WebDAVSharp.Server](https://github.com/WebDAVSharp/WebDAVSharp.Server) as base for a WebDAV Server which runs in a (MS)SQL backend, meaning all files/data is stored in DB.

I added the nu-get package of `WebDAVSharp.Server` to the `WebDAVSharp.SQLExample` project but still, it shows me missing references. For eg.: in the `WebDAVSharp.Data->SqlStoreFileInfo.cs` the base class `WebDavFileInfoBase` is missing. (The're over 200 further errors complaining about missing references)

What makes me curious is the fact I can't find this class in both repos, which basically means it doesnt exist (if I didnt simply overread something).

Does anyone have similiar troubles with WebDAVSharp.SQLExample or does it build without errors (missing references) for you ? If so, I would be very glad about a clue/hint what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently noted that winterleaf created a [pull request](https://github.com/WebDAVSharp/WebDAVSharp.Server/pull/5) in `WebDAVSharp.Server` which integrated the missing files and assemblies.

So in order to successfully build the `WebDAVSharp.SQLExample` one need a `development` build of `WebDAVSharp.Server` which integrates this pull request.

That's it.